# (node:2724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**The Error:**

```
(node:2724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\ESP\Desktop\jetSerenity\Bots\jetMusic\Commands\upload.js:20:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:2724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2724) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**The Code:**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`);

const fs = require('fs')
const request = require(`request`);

module.exports = {
    name: 'upload',
    description: 'command used to upload .mp3 file',
    async execute(message, args){
        const HelpEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Test')
            .setColor(0xff0000)
            .setDescription('Hello there ESP')
        message.channel.send(HelpEmbed);
        // Test 
        let fileMessage = await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 300000 })
        request.get(fileMessage.attachments.first().url)
            .on('error', console.error)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./MusicFiles'));
    }
}
```

**What I Want To Do:**

I basically want it to prompt a Embed which I've already setup as test, then await for an attachment to be sent, and then download the attachment and put it in a folder, any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The error means `fileMessage` has no `attchment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [`awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) is resolved, it gives you a *collection* of messages, not just a single message.

You have set the `max` option to `1`, so it will only contain one message, but this one message is still inside a collection.

Try something like this:

```
fileMessage.first().attachments.first().url
```

I recommend to rename `fileMessage` to `fileMessages`, so it is more clear that it is a collection.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to have fixed the Attachment Get URL problem!

Comment: But it gives me some illegal dir error, I'll see if i can fix that, :)